# Adding symbols to Linux configuration

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm trying to add a GPU driver.

I add the symbols to the default configuration I'm using however they do not appear in the generated configuration.

I've modified the Makefile present in drivers/gpu to account for the new folder I added.

**Edit1** 
I added a folder for the driver in the folder driver/gpu and on the Makefile added the name of the folder.
On my defconfig I added the symbols required to compile the driver I just added.

Comment: What exactly you change in configuration file? (You mean `.config` file, don't you?) What exactly you modify in `drivers/gpu/Makefile`? Add this info into your question.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I've added the required information.

Comment: **What code** you have added into that files? **What behaviour you expect**? **What behaviour you observed**? It is unclear what you ask.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I expect the code added to compile a driver for the ARM Mali GPU. By adding it I expect it's symbols to be available and that by selecting them the driver would be compiled. As such I added them to my defconfig, however after I do make my_defconfig the new symbols I selected to not appear in the .config file.

Comment: Original `drivers/gpu/Makefile` contains only 6 lines. Can you provide content of your resulted file? For add configuration option, you need to modify one of `Kbuild` file. Have you done that?

Comment: @Tsyvarev the folder gpu doesn't not contain a Kbuild file. I've added the following to the obj-y := line-> mali/

Comment: If you have appended `mali/` to the existed `obj-y :=` line, your driver in `mali` directory should be compiled unconditionally, without being dependent on configuration. If you have added `obj-y := mali/` before that line, your assignment to the variable is overwritten after. That's why your driver is not built.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have appended it to the original line. The line stands as such: obj-y := drm/ vga/ mali/ yet during compilation no gpu drivers are even touched despite the fact I've configured the symbol CONFIG_MALI.

Comment: You didn't show how your driver is dependent from `CONFIG_MALI`. Please, add a few lines of code(Makefile/Kbuild/...) into your question. It is very difficult to help with code, if it is not shown.

Comment: @Tsyvarev the Kbuild system wasn't recognizing the Kconfig file so it was removing the options.